# UIScrollView makes UITextField stop calling UIPicker

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uitextfield, uipicker

To start off.  I have researched this on SO and elsewhere and have not found an exact answer to the problem.  I have seen problems similar, but not the same.  I have a fully functioning App that uses a picker to populate about 5 textfields.  When the user taps on a textfield the picker comes up and everything is great.  I recently wanted to expand the space between the textfields to make it look nicer.  But I don’t have enough room.  So I figured that I could put the textfields into a scrollview and it would be fine.  However, when I connect up my action “showYourPicker” the picker no longer comes up, the regular keyboard does.  I even tried to make the view a UITextfieldDelegate and run

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField 
{
[self showYourPicker:self];
return NO;  
}
```

to show my picker and hide the keyboard, but this doesn’t work.  I know that I have hooked up the textfield correctly, because everything goes back to working if I remove the scroll view and hook it all back up.  So what do I have to do, to get the picker to show and not the default keyboard when a textfield is inside a scrollview.  Thanks in advance.  If you need more code, just let me know.

Comment: have you set the inputView property of the textField to be your picker? That'd be the right way to do it.

Comment: @calvinBhai. Yes, I set that in the method showYourPicker.  It works in all the other tabs of the app, except the one I have put the scroll view in.  Should I set the property elsewhere?  Thanks.

Comment: ideally, you should do your textField.inputView = yourPickerView; when the textfield is created or added to the view.

Comment: So maybe in the view will appear or view did load?

Comment: yup, wherever you do your UITextField *theTextField = [[UITextField alloc] init];, right after that

Comment: I'll give it a try!  Thanks, I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: @calvinBhai, YES!!!  Thank you so much.  Can you post your comment as an answer.  It worked!  I moved all my "creating the picker and determining the input view" to the view did load method and it all works fine.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wherever you are doing this

```
UITextField *theTextField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
```

right after that do this

```
textField.inputView = yourPickerView;
```